# Jtable filtering failed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, filtering, rowfilter

I have a Jtable an i want to filter it based on user entries.
I have write this code:

```
data_table = new JTable(model); // create data table

data_table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(pin, colNames)); // fill jtable
model = new DefaultTableModel(pin, colNames); // create a table model

final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;

sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);

data_table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

and on click i have this code:

```
String text = filter_txtf.getText(); // i get the user entry from a text field
    if (text.length() == 0) {
     sorter.setRowFilter(null);
      //data_table.setRowSorter(sorter);  
    } else {
      try {
        sorter.setRowFilter(
            RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
        //data_table.setRowSorter(sorter);  
      } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
        System.err.println("Bad regex pattern");
     }
   }
```

The problem is that on click nothing happens, i debug my program and the 'actionperformed' called normally. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Basic code looks reasonable, but we can't see the context of how the code is used since you didn't provide a `SSCCE`. No need for if/else statement, just always reset the row filter.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.